# Web services - How do comparator-like webapps work? They can only query sites that have JSON or XML APIs?

Tags: web-services, web

I have only made one app that uses web services. It was for querying IMDb data, and I used [OMDb API](http://www.omdbapi.com/). It returns a JSON (or XML) you have to parse, a very simple work.

But I am wondering how do comparator-like sites work. I mean, they obtain the information from webs which have no an API, or at least I can't find it.

Is it possible to extract information from websites which don't have an specific API?